# How to get parameters from a login_required route in flask?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have been trying to understand an error for a while now, and have come to the conclusion that @login_required is not allowing me to pull values from the route in my function

```
@main.route('/follow/<user_id>')
@login_required
def follow_user(user_id):
    referrer = request.headers.get("Referer")

    target_user = User.query.get(user_id)
```

When I pass the user_id parameter to the query it returns None( it returns the correct value if I manually enter a user id in there) and I need a way to get a reference to the user being followed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `@login_required` **does allow** parameters in your view function. Make sure, when you use `url_for()` in your HTML or Jinja2 you pass a valid id, which should be of type `int`. You can check if the id is valid by hovering over the view function reference link to see its structure.  In any case, please provide enough code so we can understand the problem better.

Comment: console the type of int that you are getting from form. If that's a str type and in ur db you are using int type then use type converion. Just check this and tell these two types

Comment: Is `user_id` a string or an int? Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks, guys, It was the type creating a problem. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, it was the type creating the problem, a quick int(user_id) fixed it ‍♂️.

Answer (score 0):

If this snippet is really complete...

```
@main.route('/follow/<user_id>')
@login_required
def follow_user(user_id):
    referrer = request.headers.get("Referer")

    target_user = User.query.get(user_id)
```

... then of course you get a `None` as you return nothing, and Python implicitly returns None.

**Example**

```
>>> def ret():
...     pass
... 
>>> None is ret()
True
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis(ret)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: The database query returns None, not the function.